# Conditional Viewport for Windows Mobile 7.8

Tags: html, css, viewport, ie-mobile

I would like to remove the viewport for Windows Phone 7.8 meaning that users do not see a responsive site.

We have tried setting as follows:

```
<!--[if gte IEMobile 7]>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<![endif]-->
<![if !IEMobile 7]>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<![endif]>
```

But this appears to be ignored.

Is there a better/correct way to do this?